# h:button and f:param JSF 2.1

Tags: button, jsf-2, parameter-passing

I have to add a button to an existing page.
I am using JSF 2.1.11, with faces-config version 2.1.

I am trying to use the following code:

`<h:button value="Show Image" outcome="viewImage">
    <f:param name="imageId" value="#{somebean.imageId}" />
</h:button>`

**Without** `<f:param ...>`, the page loads without exception.

**With** `<f:param ...>` an exception occurs because 
JSF can't locate a boolean property on the page bean.  This unfound property determines whether to render a panel component.

- The `<h:button>` is not contained within that panel.
- The exposed boolean property does exist.

If I remove the `<f:param ...>` line, the page loads fine.

Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: the error appears when you load the page with the button? or when you click the button? did you include getter/setter for that boolean property?

Comment: Yes the get/set exists for the boolean property.  I just tested again, same result: with <f:param...> line, page exception because JSF can't find the boolean property (which has no apparent logical relation with the <h:button> and its <f:param>).

Answer (score 0):

For no clearly understood reasons, now it works.
The problem was probably caused by corruption somewhere in the project or Tomcat 7 server.

I hate to be so inconclusive, but I performed the following steps several times, which sometimes worked, sometimes not: (1) eclipse project clean from project menu
(2) project clean from ant script (3) Tomcat clean (4) rebuild and redeploy

I also added this to web.xml: com.sun.faces.expressionFactorycom.sun.el.ExpressonFactoryImpl.

In sum, this now works:

```
<h:button value="Show Image" outcome="viewImage">
    <f:param "imageId" value="#{someBean.imageId}"/>
</h:button>
```

Your mileage may vary!